# Call method from jsp using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a condition where i want to pass EL, `element.dept_id` as parameter and get the name of department from a method as return. I want it directly from view page if possible.
However, the return will be object of type department and i want to print the name of department. Any help? Can it be done without using scriptlet?

```
class Department{
Private Integer id;
Private String name;
//getters
//setters
}

 <c:forEach items="${empImpl.allEmployee}" var="element">

      <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${element.name}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${element.gender}" /></td>

    <td><c:out value="${element.salary}" /></td>

    <td>Something like this // deptImpl.name(${element.dept_id})  </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by defining a custom EL function taking an id and returning your department. Check out [Custom Tags and Custom EL Functions in JSP Pages](http://blog.idleworx.com/2010/04/custom-tags-and-custom-el-functions-in.html) for an example of how to create a custome EL function.

However, I'd recomend just having your servlet populate the request with the data you want to display since that would make your code easier to maintain.